# How to create undo function in SnackBar widget that restore Firestore data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, android-snackbar

I want my Flutter apps to be able to restore deleted data in my `ListTile` widget as well as in my Firestore. I have `SnackBar` as below:

```
return Dismissible(
  key: Key(documentID), 
  onDismissed: (direction) {
  var deleteItem = list.removeAt(index);
    setState(() async{
    isDeleting = true;
    if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
      await deleteData(log_id: documentID); // To delete the data in firebase
      deleteItem;
      
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
       SnackBar(
         behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
         duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
         content: Text("${ds['food_name']} has been deleted",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
         action: SnackBarAction(
            label: "UNDO",
            textColor: AppColors.MAIN_COLOR,
            onPressed: () {
               list.insert(index, deleteItem); // this didn't work in my case
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  }
                                              });
    setState(() {
     isDeleting = false;
  });
},
```

I managed to delete the data in the ListTile and Firestore but im unable to restore them in both ListTile and Firestore with this line `list.insert(index, deleteItem)` once 'UNDO' is pressed.
This is how I declared the `list` -> `final list = snapshot.data.docs;` So, how do I achieve this?

I dont need an AlertDialog (I've seen this example when I was googling), I just want a SnackBar with 'UNDO' button that is able to perform the desired function. I am very new to Flutter/Dart so a little guidance is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Updated code with the following solution

1. remove from list.
2. show Undo snackbar.
3. if no action then only delete from firebase.
4. if yes undo action then just add back to the list.

```
bool isUndoPressed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
        child: Container(),
        key: Key(''),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
            var deleteItem = list.removeAt(index);
            setState(() {
              isDeleting = true;
            });

            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                content: Text("${['food_name']} has been deleted",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: "UNDO",
                  textColor: AppColors.MAIN_COLOR,
                  onPressed: () {
                    isUndoPressed = true;
                    setState(() {
                      isDeleting = false;
                      list.insert(
                          index, deleteItem); // this didn't work in my case
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
            //start a 3s timer
            Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
              if (isUndoPressed) {
                 //can if undo button is pressed.
                timer.cancel();
                 setState(() {
                  isDeleting = false;
                });
              } else {
                await deleteData(
                    log_id: documentID); // To delete the data in firebase
                isUndoPressed = false;
                setState(() {
                  isDeleting = false;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `list.insert(index, deleteItem)in setState method` is only able to restore data in ListTile but not in Firebase because once you delete a document in Firestore, it's gone for good. There is no undelete feature.

What you're trying to do is likely not very easy with the adapter provided by FirebaseUI. The only ways you can reasonably implement an undo feature is :

- Have the delete function not actually delete the document, and
  instead just update the UI to remove the view. You would have to
  schedule the deletion to happen some time later. The undo option
  would then just restore the visibility of the deleted document and
  cancel the delayed deletion.
- For that also add a new boolean field to the document to mark that
  it's deleted or not, and use that in a filter for the query you pass
  to FirebaseUI. The field would have to be present on every document
  in order for it to filter correctly. After the UI is done, you would
  then have to figure out how to actually delete all the documents you
  marked for deletion in the UI.
- Or you can create the document in another collection before deleting
  it from the main one. For example, a common implementation is to have
  a subcollection with deleted documents, or even the entire history of
  each document.